# Why do we have "anxiousness", but not "frightenness"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Why do we have the word "anxiousness", but not the word "frighteness"? Both would mean something similar: "Being anxious" respectively Being frightened"

ps: To make it even more analogous, I could accept "frightenedness" as well.

Comment: What evidence is there that *anxiousness* is an established word, when *anxiety* is already common and serves the same purpose?  Similarly, *fear* is probably the noun you are looking for. Can you give some examples of situations when the simple words are not enough?

Comment: I forgot to mention anything about anxiety for contrast until I read your comment. Regardless anxiousness is a well established word that I've heard often. Merriam-Webster's online dictionary lists -ness in the list of suffixes for anxious, whereas Oxford's has its own entry.

Comment: You have *fearfulness*. Why do you need *frightenedness*?

Comment: @PeterShor *Fearful* and *frightened* are a bit different, I'd say - which leaves room for *frightenedness* next to *fearfulness*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Derivational suffixes like -ness can be added to only one part of speech. In your example "anxiousness", -ness was added to "anxious", and "anxious" is an adjective.  So, you'd expect to able to add -ness to other adjectives, but not to other things.  This is why *"frightness" doesn't work -- "fright" is a different part of speech.  It's a noun.  (And *"frightenness" would be formed by adding -ness to a verb -- also bad.)

But "frightenedness" conforms to the rule, since "frightened" is an adjective.  However, it's a little awkward, since it has so many suffixes, fright-en-ed-ness, and since "fright" was already a noun, it's roundabout to add 3 suffixes to get it to be a noun.

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: @Tonepoet, good point.

Comment: This is the best answer for why we don't have 'frightenness'. However I somewhat disagree with the reason for the lack of 'frightenedness' because that would suggest 'fear,' which may be used as either a verb or a noun, should block the formation of 'fearfulness'. The suffixes have a subtle meaning change beyond simple word reclassification, so it would mean a slightly different thing. Only somewhat though because 'frightenedness" is a bit of a mouthful, particularly where the new suffix is added. (Note: I'm sorry Greg, I deleted my comment to clarify something)

Answer (score 2):

We already have the noun *fright* and it would tend to block the formation of an abstract noun formed from the past participle: *frightenedness.

Comment: To say nothing of the horror that is *anxioused*.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because "[Fright](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=fright&use1828=on)" is too transient of an emotion to use that combination of suffixes. It comes suddenly and vanishes momentarily. "[Frighten](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=frighten&use1828=on)" means to inflict fright upon something. "[Frightened](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=frightened&use1828=on)" means something had that feeling inflicted upon it.

Now that we have a working definition of frightened, we would have to add the suffix [-ness](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=-ness&use1913=on&use1828=on). That suffix means to have a quality or be in a "[State](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=state&use1828=on)/[Condition](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=condition&use1828=on)". Fright already describes being in the condition of being momentarily startled with fear, therefore in order for "Frightenedness" to be considered distinct from "Fright" or "Frightened", it would need to mean to have the quality of having once been startled with fear by something in the past for brief period of time.

I believe this is fairly pointless if it is not self-contradictory. As an everlasting quality "Frightenedness" would apply to virtually everybody because most people have once been scared by something. As a temporary state, it would imply that you are still frightened, in which case "[Fear](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=fear&use1828=on)" is the better root word since that describes the same duration and hence "[Fearfulness](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=fearfulness&use1828=on)" would probably be the more apt word to use.

"[Anxious](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=anxiety&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on)" by contrast does not imply any duration, so people could be considered in a prolonged state of it and hence "[Anxiousness](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=anxiousness&use1828=on)" can contextually make sense if you need to describe the trait of being anxious. Granted, "[Anxiety](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=anxiety&use1828=on)" means virtually the same thing as "Anxiousness" but despite appearances, it is not technically the same base word so distinctiveness is not as much of a consideration.

All referenced definitions can be found in [Noah Webster's American Dictionary of the English Language (1828)](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/).